# Как изменить перевод элементов интерфейса на этом сайте?

Tags: поддержка

На сайтах StackExchange многое могут делать пользователи сайтов - создавать тэги вопросов, редактировать описания этих тегов и т. д. Но есть и элементы названия и описания которых пользователи менять не могут (и, наверное, не могут это сделать и модераторы). Есть ли способ предложить правки в интерфейс?

Опытным пользователям, разумеется, без разницы как называется та или иная кнопка - они знают, что "для того чтобы сделать это, нужно нажать вот сюда", но новых пользователей названия могут сбивать с толку.

Вот, например, заголовок вопроса называется "Тема". Многие пользователи вписывают туда что-то вроде "Использование глаголов прошедшего времени...", хотя, на самом деле, их не интересует 15 параграфов описания всех возможных случаев, а конкретный глагол в конкретном предложении.

Возможно стоит переименовать "Тему" в "Короткое описание" или "Заголовок" (или еще как-то по другому)?

Или вот "знаки" - должны быть "значки" (как у скаутов). Отдельные названия значков тоже удивительные - есть "голос народа", а есть "глас народа". И так далее, и тому подобное.

Есть ли способ изменить переводы элементов интерфейса и как это делать?

Comment: Насчет знаков-значков. Если все правильно помню, то когда делали перевод (я по личным мотивам выпал из активного участия, но потом ознакомился), решили что знаки - точнее. С остальным - согласен. Перевод достаточно сырой. Хотя лично мне нисколько не мешает ))). Но какой-то механизм коллективного уточнения должен быть.

Comment: Кстати, подобный воопрос уже поднимался, скорее всего - не один раз. http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите участвовать в переводе этого сайта, то вам нужно делать это через Мету StackOverflow на русском. Вот входная точка: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/181472)

Comment: Спасибо, гляну что там и как.

Comment: А линк нарочно рваный?  Я бы рад исправить, но на Мете не можно...

Comment: @VictorBazarov спасибо, исправил.